# php insert data from fetch array to other table on version 5.4

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have moved to IIS 8 in PHP 5.4. I am trying to collect data from a table and insert them to a different one, i know my code is correct, but seems to be not working, probably because of the php version, can anyone help me?

here's my code

```
$query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM member");

while($rows = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {

$querystring = "INSERT INTO oldusers (username, password, regdate) VALUES ('$rows['userid']', '$rows['passwd']', '$rows['registdate']')";
$query2 = odbc_exec($conn, $querystring);
odbc_free_result($query2);

//echo $rows['userid']." ".$rows['passwd']." ".$rows['registdate']."<br>";
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: my code is not working* means what? are you getting any errors?

Comment: please check my edits, this my prob was about inserting it to the other table, i am getting 500 internal server error only cause its in IIS8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're placing `$rows['passwd']` inside of a double-quoted string. Instead you should do:

```
$str = "some sql $rows[passwd] rest of sql"; // notice the absence of single quotes
```

or:

```
$str = "some sql {$rows['passwd']} rest of sql";
```

or (I think this way is most readable):

```
$str = 'some sql' . $rows[passwd] . ' rest of sql';
```

If your column contains text you'll need to add surrounding single quotes where necessary.

Having said all that, **you should instead use parameterized queries** (if your database supports it) as it's safer (from SQL injection). If that's unavailable you will at the very least need to escape the data before concatenating it to the string.

Comment: so is this correct? 
$querystring = 'INSERT INTO oldusers (username, password, regdate) VALUES ('.$rows['userid'].', '.$rows['passwd'].', '.$rows['registdate'].')';

Comment: If your column stores text then you'll need to surround the value with single quotes. Also please remember to escape your data to avoid SQL injection (and, if possible, use parameterized queries instead).

Answer (score 1):

instead trying to insert one by one record, better to insert like below:

```
INSERT INTO oldusers (username, password, regdate) SELECT userid,passwd,registdate FROM member
```

for more information :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html